# Rails 5.1 Capistrano Deploying with secrets.yml.key

Tags: deployment, capistrano, secret-key, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I'm attempting to deploy to a staging environment with capistrano.
I've set up my encrypted secrets and tested on development, and the secrets appear available. I've setup the staging environment config for `read_encrypted_secrets = true`. My secret key file is git-ignored. I have ssh'ed into my staging environment and placed the `secrets.yml.key` in the `app_name/current/config` directory. I am deploying to an AWS EC2 instance. I am not using the `RAILS_MASTER_KEY` environment variable.

When I run `cap staging deploy` and choose my release tag, I run into this error during `deploy:migrating` `bundle exec rake db:migrate`

```
01 rake aborted!
01 Rails::Secrets::MissingKeyError: Missing encryption key to decrypt secrets with. Ask your team for your master key and put it in ENV["RAILS_MASTER_KEY"]
```

I have the correct key on the server, why isn't rails finding/using it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `app_name/current` path is just a symlink to the newest Capistrano release. That means that the contents of `app_name/current/config` will change every time you run `cap staging deploy`. If you manually add a file to that directory via ssh, it will no longer be there on the subsequent deploy.

The proper way to add a configuration file to the server that will persist across all deploys is to place it in the **shared** directory. Specifically:

1. Via ssh (or scp), place your key file at `app_name/shared/config/secrets.yml.key`.
2. Locally, in `deploy.rb`, add the following:

   ```
   append :linked_files, "config/secrets.yml.key"
   ```

Now run `cap staging deploy`.

Comment: Hello. I have a similar issue. Can it be "cap production deploy" instead? I'm confused.

Answer (score 3):

This also works for Rails 5.2 and the encrypted ENV variables:

`append :linked_files, "config/master.key"`